# How to put a huge list between the <option> tags for a select form field?

Tags: html-select

Sorry guys i'm new in this.

I need to make a site with a lot of categories and i don't have the time to put every list item between the opening and closing option tags.
Its a big amount of words. 
So is there some kind of generator who can nest a entire list between the opening and closing option tags for a select form field? Or do i have to write everything by my self between this tags?
Would be very great to have some solution for this thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would recommend Zen Coding with NotePad++ (or another supported IDE):

http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/

You can select a set of items each on a separate line:

[image]

Go to `Zen Coding > Wrap with Abbreviation` and type in `option*`:

[image]

Each item in the list will be surrounded with the option tag:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could generate your code with Excel or Excel like programs like Open Office Calc

Else, you can use the Notepad++ macro.

Personally i would use Notepad++ macro to do the job. It's very simple and will take you only a couple minutes. Use CTRL+SHIFT+R to start recording and the hit CTRL+SHIFT+R to end the recording. Finally press CTRL+SHIFT+P until everything is between the option tag.